# Add a property in the dam metadata in touch ui AEM 6.2

Tags: aem, dam

I have a use case.
While going to [DAM Asset Dialog](http://localhost:4502/mnt/overlay/dam/gui/content/assets/metadataeditor.html?item=%2Fcontent%2Fdam%2Fprojects%2Foutdoors%2Fcover&_charset_=utf8) in AEM 6.2,I want to add a property `rootPath: /etc/tags/geometrixx` to the tags field.

I am using the concept of overlay and resourceMerger.
My dialog is under this

> /libs/dam/content/schemaeditors/forms/default/items/tabs/items/tab1/items/col1/items/tags.

While Overlaying it in apps and add the property in it,it doesn't show anything.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Any Error you are able to see in the console?

Comment: no.Please try this at your end.

Answer (score 0):

Just for testing i have replicated, and it works fine as expected
[image: Overlay DAM Asset Tags porperty]

Comment: Please tell me the steps.You overlay or just copy the structure.Which version you are working with?

Comment: make sure you have the same folder types when you overlay as of libs, and i just copied the items node and added the rootpath property for the tags node. I have tested this in AEM 6.1

Below are the folder types i have created to overlay:
/apps/dam -- nt:folder
/apps/dam/content -- sling:Folder
/apps/dam/content/schemaeditors -- sling:Folder
/apps/dam/content/schemaeditors/forms -- sling:OrderedFolder
/apps/dam/content/schemaeditors/forms/default -- sling:OrderedFolder

Comment: Please try it once with AEM 6.2.I have tried all this.But not successful till now

Comment: @ShivaniGarg For 6.2 implementation of forms overlay, Have a look over here from [adobe forum](http://help-forums.adobe.com/content/adobeforums/en/experience-manager-forum/aem-assets.topic.html/forum__8qjp-i_am_tryingtooverl.html)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can't do that by overlaying the dialog, you'll need to rely in DAM Metadata Schemas to achieve that - https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-64/assets/administer/metadata-schemas.html?lang=en

From there, and if you want to persist these definitions in your code baseline, you can refer to the location where it gets stored - /conf/global/settings/dam/adminui-extension/metadataschema

Hope it helps